# Biopython installation for Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: biopython

I need to install `Biopython` for my laptop, Windows 7 win 64. I have checked the website and I can only find for 32 bit. Can I install this on my laptop? The 64 bit is unofficial and I'm not willing to download it.

Comment: You can download from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#biopython). This is a well-known, well-trusted repository with many many users.

Comment: Hi, I only havea problem now. Which one of all of the window list is the one I should download? Thanks

Comment: You download the 64-bit `.whl` for the version of Python you have installed on your system. The file naming scheme should be very obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in downloading the 32 bit version. It will work on 64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to use the precompiled version, you can download it from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#biopython
  e.g. `biopython-1.68-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`
- `cp##` is the python version and `amd64` stands for the 64bit version. Copy the file to your python directory in the subfolder `Scripts`.
- Next you need to use the windows command line.

e.g.

```
cd your\python\directory
cd Scripts
pip install biopython-1.68-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

- Alternatively you can compile it yourself, see [here](http://biopython.org/wiki/64-bit_Windows_Biopython) for a short manual.